# Why does merged observable sequence not signal in the same way as one of its constituent sequences?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

See two unit tests below (`ReactiveObject` comes from [ReactiveUI](http://github.com/ReactiveUI/ReactiveUI)). The only difference is that the first unit test monitors a merged sequence and the second monitors one of the sequences being merged. The first unit test fails while the second one passes.

**UPDATE:** Specifically, the first unit test fails on the last assert because hitCount is zero rather than 1. Second unit test succeeds.

Why does the first unit test **fail**?

```
[TestFixture]
public class ReactiveListTests : ReactiveObject
{
    private bool _showAll;

    private IReactiveDerivedList<Node> _nodes;

    public bool ShowAll
    {
        get { return _showAll; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _showAll, value); }
    }

    public class Node : ReactiveObject
    {
        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isSelected, value); }
        }

        private bool _isHidden;
        public bool IsHidden
        {
            get { return _isHidden; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isHidden, value); }
        }

        public ReactiveList<Node> Nodes { get; private set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Nodes = new ReactiveList<Node>(scheduler: Scheduler.Immediate) { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };
        }
    }


    [Test]
    public void WhenInnerReactiveListItemIsChanged_ThenObservableShouldBeSignaled()
    {
        var inner = new[] { new Node() { Nodes = { new Node() } } };
        var nodes = new ReactiveList<Node>(inner, scheduler: Scheduler.Immediate);

        // set up combined signal
        var nodeChanged = nodes.Select(node => node.Nodes.ItemChanged).Merge().Select(_ =>
            {
                return Unit.Default;
            });
        var showAllToggled = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.ShowAll).Select(_ => 
            {
                return Unit.Default;
            });
        var signal = nodeChanged.Merge(showAllToggled);

        _nodes = nodes.CreateDerivedCollection(node => node,
                                               node => ShowAll || node.Nodes.Any(innerNode => !innerNode.IsHidden),
                                               null,
                                               signal);

        // whenever inner node item changes, increment
        int hitCount = 0;
        signal.Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                hitCount++;
            });

        Assert.AreEqual(0, hitCount);

        _nodes[0].Nodes[0].IsSelected = true;

        Assert.AreEqual(1, hitCount);
    }


    [Test]
    public void WhenInnerReactiveListItemIsChanged_ThenObservableShouldBeSignaled2()
    {
        var inner = new[] { new Node() { Nodes = { new Node() } } };
        var nodes = new ReactiveList<Node>(inner, scheduler: Scheduler.Immediate);

        // set up combined signal
        var nodeChanged = nodes.Select(node => node.Nodes.ItemChanged).Merge().Select(_ =>
            {
                return Unit.Default;
            });
        var showAllToggled = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.ShowAll).Select(_ => 
            {
                return Unit.Default;
            });
        var signal = nodeChanged.Merge(showAllToggled);

        _nodes = nodes.CreateDerivedCollection(node => node,
                                               node => ShowAll || node.Nodes.Any(innerNode => !innerNode.IsHidden),
                                               null,
                                               signal);

        // whenever inner node item changes, increment
        int hitCount = 0;
        nodeChanged.Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                hitCount++;
            });

        Assert.AreEqual(0, hitCount);

        _nodes[0].Nodes[0].IsSelected = true;

        Assert.AreEqual(1, hitCount);
    }
```